# XAML label to C# code for creating dynamic labels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created labels in XAML that are multiline and all lines are centered, tested and working perfectly fine. Now I want to create these labels dynamically but unfortunately I don't know how to do this.

- tried setting LineStackingStrategy on MaxHeight, Fontfamily
- tried creating new Textblock on fontfamily

XAML Code to reproduce in C# code:

```
<Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Name="btn_02" Height="70" Width="160" BorderBrush="#F0F2A4" BorderThickness="2" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#F0F2A4" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="13" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="17" Content="ORGEL&#xa;LADEN" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,200,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Btn_02_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

C# code to create label dynamically:

```
Label label = new Label()
                    {
                        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                        Name = "orgel" + i.ToString(),
                        Height = 70,
                        Width = 160,
                        BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#F0F2A4")),
                        BorderThickness = new Thickness(2),
                        Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                        Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#F0F2A4")),
                        FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"),
                        FontSize = 13,
                        Content = orgel,
                        Margin = new Thickness((columncount * 100), (rowcount * 100), 0, 0)

                    };
```

I want to add  `TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" TextBlock.LineHeight="17" Content="ORGEL&#xa;LADEN" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"` from XAML to this C# code.

Comment: See also the hundreds of other questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+dynamic+labels

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to create UI elements dynamically you should think of a `DataTemplate` first. Use a `ItemsControl` to create UI elements simply by adding data to the `ObservableCollection` that serves as the `Binding.Source` of `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. The `DataTemplate` is used to define the appearance of the items (a `Label`in your case).

[Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<string> labelContents;
  public ObservableCollection<string> LabelContents
  {
    get => this.labelContents;
    set
    {
      this.labelContents = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  public void ViewModel()
  {
    // Initialize the data binding source of the ListView
    this.LabelContents = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  public void CreateLabelDynamically(string labelText)
  {    
    this.LabelContents.Add(labelText);
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

When executing `CreateLabelDynamically()` a new label in form of a `TextBlock` is added to the view.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ListView x:Name="SpectrumBars"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LabelContents}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="system:string">
        <!-- The DataContext of the TextBlock is the string value contained in LabelContents -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

It is also recommended to use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` when possible:

> When data binding the Label element's Content property to the String source object, you may experience poor performance.

[Avoid Databinding to the Label.Content Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-text#avoid-databinding-to-the-labelcontent-property)